# Databricks cannot mount Data Lake: HttpException: AADToken: HTTP connection failed for getting token from AzureAD

Tags: scala, azure-databricks

I try to mount data lake gen2 to DataBricks, but failing. Please advice me.
I wonder what is reason for HTTP error. Does this error reflect to App Registration of AD, Key Vault, Databricks secret or what? How to solve?

```
 //https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2.html#mount-adls- 
 filesystem&language-scala

//Session configuration
val applicationid = "111558b9-3525-4c62-8c48-d3d7e2c16a6a"
val secret = "111[xEPjpOIBJtBS-W9B9Zsv7h9IF:qw"
val tenantID = "111c4839-0afa-4fae-a34a-326c42112bca"
val fileSystemName = "fileshare1"
val storageaccountname = "111kensdatalake"
val mountname = "kenny"

val configs = Map(
  "fs.azure.account.auth.type" -> "OAuth",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type" -> 
"org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id" -> "<applicationid>",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret" -> dbutils.secrets.get(scope ="KensKeyVault", key = 
"StorageGen2Secret"),
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint" -> "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId 
   >/oauth2/token")

// Optionally, you can add <directory-name> to the source URI of your mount point.
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://<filesystemname>@<storageaccountname>.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mountPoint = "/mnt/<mountname>",
  extraConfigs = configs)

//ERROR:
```

shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator$HttpExcepti 
   on: AADToken: HTTP connection failed for getting token from AzureAD. Http response: 400 Bad Request

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii Content-Length: 324 Request ID:  Proxies: none
First 1K of Body: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 
4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Endpoint URL do match with AAD->App Registration->Endpoints->Token Endpoint

Comment: Make sure you are passing the correct session configurations? Please do cross check the values provided?